# Router cannot ping an IP-Camera attached to a switch

Tags: networking, routing, ping, switch, vlan

My router cannot ping an IP-Camera attached to a switch. Therefore I cannot reach this IP-Camera from over the internet using port forwarding.

[image]

Other PCs can ping the IP-Camera within the network. The router cannot.

The IP-Camera is connected to the switch. The switch is connected to the router.

**(I have another switch but disconnect it when doing any testing/changes)**

I have tried connecting the IP-Camera directly to the router and it pings successfully.

**ADSL Router DSL-2890AL** - [Manual](ftp://files.dlink.com.au/products/DSL-2890AL/Manuals/DSL-2890AL_A1_Manual_v2.10(AU).pdf)

```
IP: 192.168.0.1 | 255.255.255.0  
DHCP: enabled, IP 100-200 (most of my devices are static) Relay is disabled.
```

[image]

[image]

**Switch TL-SG2210P** - [Manual](http://www.tp-link.com.au/resources/document/TL-SG2210P_V1_UG.pdf)

```
IP: 192.168.0.28 | 255.255.255.0  
Gateway: 192.168.0.1  
DHCP: not featured
```

[image]

[image]

**IP-Camera Network Config**
http://www.longse.com/Info/View_pro.asp?id=762

```
IP: 192.168.0.27  
Netmask: 255.255.255.0  
Default Gateway: 192.168.0.1  
DNS: 192.168.0.1
```

### **Ping patterns from router to Devices**

```
SUCCESS: IP-Camera[ip27] connected to router as ethernet + power
FAIL: IP-Camera[ip27] connected to switch to router as POE
FAIL: IP-Camera[ip27] connected to switch to router as ethernet + power supply

SUCCESS: Laptop[ip24] connected to switch to router
```

Comment: Questions... Can you post the IP configuration for 192.168.0.27? Any software firewall products running on it? Is the PC able to otherwise communicate with the router / connect to the internet?

Comment: I see... thanks. So VLANs shouldn't be an issue but did you make any other configuration changes to the switch, or is it just configured to be a "dumb" switch? Is port isolation restricting any traffic between the IP camera port and the router? Do you see any warnings / errors in the switch's log table?

Comment: @BrianC: port isolation is default. I have posted a screen shot. Any trial config changes are reversed immediately and is otherwise default. I am now going to restore defaults to switch before reassigning basic network config. Be back with result soon.

Comment: @BrianC: I have reset to factory defaults and only applied correct system time and IP address 28 & gateway 01. Still no ping

Comment: @BrianC: no errors in log of switch

Comment: On the router, using the "Ping Test" widget, can you ping the 'Laptop' ?

Comment: Dumb question from me perhaps, but have you enabled SNMP on the switch? Ping uses SNMP packets.... I spent 30 mins on mine just now before I realised it was disabled...

Comment: Can you ping from the router to any other device? Eg can you ping the laptop? Also, consider using Wireshark to analyze the traffic on your network. This may help you to identify the gap in this problem.

Comment: @MartinMiles ping uses ICMP not SNMP. Unless the router has some bizarre implementation of ping the two protocols should be mutually exclusive and not interfere with each other.

Comment: Can you try a trace route from both ends?

Comment: @root: I have posted "Ping patterns from router to devices" results in my post. Also, have installed wireshark and am learning and diagnosing today.

Comment: @n_stan: pls see previous comment.

Comment: @Valamas The settings and configurations you posted look correct, I see no error in the setup. You mentioned you have another switch. Do you get different results if you swap switches? Alternatively (albeit, I'm not sure what this would really be testing), I'd be interested in removing the laptop from the network, changing the camera's IP to that of the laptop's and even go so far as to using the same port on the switch that the laptop was using. Just for kicks.

Comment: @root: i changed to the other switch. Camera+power+ethernet pings successfully. I also changed the IP of the camera to a never unused before IP, fails.

Comment: @Valamas Keep good notes on what you're changing as you test so you can correctly identify the solution. Glad the other switch works, but I'm sure you don't want to keep this configuration. Reset the original, non-working switch. My idea with using the laptop's IP was to use a previously-known (and reachable) address.

Comment: @root (laptop was offline on previous comment too and also tried same ip as laptop). Also tested laptop has internet access through switch.

Comment: @root ty. have been performing only one change at a time and immediately reversing it to match the base setup after testing it.

Comment: Can you try using `arping` instead of `ping`? It uses ARP packets instead of ICMP packets, so we shall immediately know whether it is a problem with the protocol.  A possible command would be `arping -b -c1 -I eth0 192.168.0.27`.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: Performed arping windows style. PC can ping IP-Camera, just not the router. Looked into telnet to router without success. Not sure what else to try or report.

Comment: @Valamas Since the alternative switch produced positive results, I would be keen to resetting the switch that is failing to factory defaults.

Comment: @root: the switch has been factory reset recently. It currently only has ip and time set.

Comment: @Valamas and the problem still occurs? Why don't you stop by chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access

Comment: @root: ty, i have joined the chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with TP-link and their failure to display a correct list of firmware as I needed a firmware update.

However, TP-link had the firmware linked on .com.au website and .com website. The .com.au was missing a page update listing two more versions when compared to the .com web page.

Other than the missing updates, the page design was the same.

TP-link support was good but their failure to update or have a single page for the english site cost me days in time and frustrating testing.

Answer (score 2):

Doh, ICMP of course!! 
I have the exact same setup as you and have been messing around for hours. Are far as I can tell the only thing I have done is to change the switch IP onto the same network as the router 192.168.0.nnn and enabled then disabled SNMP and suddenly everything works.
I have also just updated the firmware to the latest version from the TP-link website but ping was working before I did that.
In all honesty the only thing that appears to have made ping work is by enabling SNMP and now after disabling it  - ping still works.

I can't explain it - and it makes no sense - but it worked!

Comment: SNMP was disabled by default. I enabled, rebooted, pinged, then disabled, rebooted, pinged. In all scenarios ping did not work from router to ip-camera.

Also, firmware was the latest version already.

Answer (score 1):

If your PCs can ping this, you should be able to access the camera and it's web page.

Your diagram shows everything plugged into the switch. So regardless if you had a router or not (you're not even using a GW really in this scenario) you still have routing access to the camera.

Looking at this you have a managed switch. Since your PCs can ping this Camera but your router cannot, my guess is the port that the router is plugged into cannot reach the port that the camera is plugged into. Check your port settings for the router and see if there is a tagging issue or something setting wise different from the other ports. If you don't have a lot of important settings, also try resetting your switch (you should be able to backup a switch config as well) and see if an out of the box switch config has the same results.

Personally,  I would start with switching the ports with a known good pingable port (Switch a PC port with the camera port and see if the results are the same or switch the router port and a PC port to see if the PC can still ping and if the router cannot etc.)

Comment: PC is not connected to the switch. Also have been switching ports and using cables in any change that were also know good pingers. I have lots of trusted cables.

Comment: I'm assuming the end result you're wanting is to view the camera outside of your network via phone etc? I would be curious what the results would be from a reset switch/router. Your switch config looks relatively basic...have you tried to reset the router/switch and pinging again? Also, does your router have ports on it? I would definitely plug the camera into one of those (where your PC is plugged into since it's not in the switch) and see if the router can get to it from there. That will answer a lot of questions I think or help narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into a similar problem - **SG2210 + 1043ND**. Client connected directly to router could ping internet/lan, but the switch was unreachable, also connecting clients to the switch resulted in `loss of connection` to **DHCP server (router)**.

Even setting the switch's admin IP to the same subnet didn't help. After installing the latest firmware everything looks goodk - however it wasn't easy to figure out that there was a newer firmware [here](http://www.tp-link.com/hu/download/TL-SG2210P.html#Firmware):

Firmware than at the first site found by google [search](http://www.tp-link.us/download/TL-SG2210P.html#Firmware). I also noticed that there are different "latest" versions for other devices (for ex. EAP120) on different sites, though they are intended for the same device and same HW version. That should be revised by TP-Link.